# Create a transparent mask overlay in CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I'm making this game where the character moves in a dark cave with a torch. I want the torch to light the area around the character so that players can see the character. I was able to do this with image, but the image must be at least 2000 x 2000px to cover enough area around the character. Because the image is 2000 x 2000 my FPS dropped from 50 to 30. Anyway to do this in CSS? Notice the visible area under the black area is NOT image but divs with backgrounds. Btw I'm making HTML/javascript game if you wonder.

[image: Game Desing]

Comment: CSS `radial-gradient` with one end black, the other `rgba(0,0,0,0)`

Comment: EDIT: The drop from 50 FPS to 30 FPS is because I must move the whole 2000x2000px image everytime the character moves. So I was wondering is it somehow possible to just fill the whole game area let's say with 5000x5000px div with background black that does not move and create moving hole in it that follow the character with image mask or something :)

Comment: It might be worth having a read through - https://css-tricks.com/clipping-masking-css/

Comment: `mask-image`, maybe, but I have the impression that browser support is too spotty for that to be really viable yet.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the box-shadow property that generates a shadow around a CSS object. To have a 'negative' shadow, you can use the 'inset' property applied to your whole screen :

```
box-shadow: inset 3px -5px 81px 97px rgba(0,0,0,0.89);
```

The first and second px properties allow it to move the negative shadow around the center.
Then you have the blur radius, the spread radius, and the RGB color (with opacity)

You can play with these settings to see the results, for example in [this](http://www.cssmatic.com/box-shadow) tool. (don't forget the inset toggle at the end).

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just `position: fixed` image, and no need for moving it around?